# Is it possible to establish connection between two applications using TCP

Tags: android, tcp, android-emulator, telnet

I have established connection between emulators using TCP protocol. I wonder if it is possible to establish connections between two applications which reside in same emulator. Although there other ways of communicating. but still i wanted to know whether it is possible or not. If so, do we need to use telnet?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  "Telent" is a protocol or program implementing it, but at a simple level it's just some features/options negotiation at the start of a TCP connection, so you can often use a telnet program to test other things at the cost of a small amount of garbage data (though preferable if you tell it not to do that negotiation).  If you use TCP your applications will need Internet permission due to the nature of the sockets.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you so much. Could you please send me ref link that support this answer or ref to TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you need to create you virtual network. And devices must be rooted.

Comment: No, you do not need to establish a virtual network (as it already exists), and no, you do not need root.